# How to set subdomain for SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, configuration, dns, subdomain, sql-server-express

I have SQL Server Express installed, which I can connect to via `mydomain.com,1433/SQLExpress`.

Is it possible to setup server or DNS to connect it by `db.mydomain.com`?

Comment: No answer yet ?